How do you parameterize simultaneous solutions to equations with expressions like "$ x +2 \left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor + 1 - [3 \mid x]$"?
Let all functions be integer functions herein.  I.e. $\Bbb{Z}\to\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{Z}$ where appropriate.
I found this jewel of floor functions.
So that made me wonder whether, we can solve for the simultaneous solution to:
$$
f(x) = g(y) 
$$
where
$$f(x) = x +2 \left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor + 1 - [3 \mid x]\\
g(y) = y + 2 \left\lfloor\frac{y}{5}\right\rfloor + 1 - [5\mid y]
$$
where $x_{k} = x \mod k$ the least non-negative residue.  And $[3\mid x]=$ Iverson bracket for whether $3$ divides $x$.
But more specifically, can we describe a single-parameter function $h(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ such that:
$$
f(x(t)) = g(y(t))
$$
?
Attempt.
$$
x + 2\frac{ x - x_{3}}{3} + 1 - [3\mid x] = y + 2\frac{ y - y_{5}}{5} + 1 - [5\mid y]
\\
\iff \\
25x +10x_{3} - 15[3\mid x ] = 21y + 6y_{5} - 15[5\mid y]
$$
Well, I've managed to reduce it for us in terms of variables modulo $3,5$, Iverson brackets and naked variables/coefficients, all "linearly" combined.

In other words how do we go about actually computing an equalizer (category theory term)?
Alternative Question.  Clearly $h(t)$ is necessarily also injective and increasing as long as $x(t), y(t)$ are.  Does this mean that in some way that the function
$$k(z) = \# \{ 0 \leq y \leq z: y = f(x(t))[=g(y(t))] \text{ for some } t \in \Bbb{N}\}
$$
has something to do with a possible parameterization?

What does $~[ ~3 ~| ~x ~] ~$ represent?

@user2661923 $[3\mid x] = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if } 3 \text{ divides } x\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$  a function $\Bbb{Z} \to {0,1} \subset \Bbb{Z}$.

My first try, which might not succeed, would be to assume that $~x = 3P + Q + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~Q \in {0,1,2}, ~0 \leq r < 1. ~$ Also, if I have understood your question correctly, it looks like you are assuming that $~x \in \Bbb{Z} \implies r = 0.$

@user2661923 you can do that (work with reals) as long as you have a definition  for $[3\mid x]$ that makes sense and the resulting value of $f, g$ are integral.

@user2661923 yes, everything must work out to be an integer because of the naked $x$ term in there, my solutions that I'm studying require exactness and integral $f,g$ values.

You can rewrite $~[ ~k ~| ~x ~] ~$ as $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{k}\right\rfloor$ if it helps

@Henry that might help if someone needs all floor expression for it

I don't know if this helps:  These functions $(x(t), y(t))$ look like a line as you zoom out.  I know how to compute the exact line's "slope" $\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}$.  Simply drop all floors, and combine the coefficients of $x$ i.e. you could definitely start from @Henry 's representation, which is all floor (no Iverson bracket).  Then the deviation of other solutions from this trendline is something small.
